# How to authenticate user with hashed password?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, passwords, password-hash, libsodium

I am trying to implement secure password storing using [libsodium](/questions/tagged/libsodium), but `docsTestWorks`, `hashesDontMatch` and `wrongPassword` seem to be *always* true. I don't think they're supposed to be. Am I doing something (or lots of things for that matter) wrong?

```
public async Task<IUser> Authenticate(ICredentials credentials)
{
    using var connection = _databaseGateway.Connection;
    connection.Open();

    const string PASSWORD = "Correct Horse Battery Staple";
    var hash = PasswordHash
        .ScryptHashString(PASSWORD);
    var docsTestWorks = PasswordHash.ScryptHashStringVerify(hash, PASSWORD);

    var incomingHash = PasswordHash
        .ScryptHashString(credentials.Password);
    var test1 = PasswordHash
        .ScryptHashString("myPassword");
    var test2 = PasswordHash
        .ScryptHashString("myPassword");
    var hashesDontMatch = test1 != test2;
    var users = await connection.GetAllAsync<User>();
    var existingUser = users
        .Single(u => u.Username == credentials.Username);
    var wrongPassword = !PasswordHash
        .ScryptHashStringVerify(existingUser.PasswordHash, credentials.Password);

    if (wrongPassword)
        throw new AuthenticationException(Error.WrongPassword,
            "Error: Incorrect Password.");

    return AddToken(existingUser);
}
```

I feel like this is oversimplistic, and I may be missing lots of things...

The package I'm using:

```
dotnet add package Sodium.Core
```

Comment: Does this `libsodium` adds salt to the hashed password? If so, they will practically never be the same.

Comment: @TonyTroeff Yes. I think it does. But then I can't see how I can pass it from outside to compare.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some extensions that use the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace to simplify this kind of work.

https://github.com/jscarle/Crypto.NET/blob/master/Crypto.NET/System.Security.Cryptography.Extensions.cs

Once added to your project, reference the namespace with `using System.Security.Cryptography`, then you can hash and compare the hash from any string.

For example:

```
string password1 = "some password";
string hash1 = password1.Hash();

string password2 = "some other password";
string hash2 = password2.Hash();

string password3 = "some password";
string hash3 = password3.Hash();

Console.WriteLine($"{password1} = {hash1}");
Console.WriteLine($"{password2} = {hash2}");
Console.WriteLine($"{password3} = {hash3}");

if (password1.CompareToHash(hash2))
    Console.WriteLine("hash1 and hash2 match.");
else
    Console.WriteLine("hash1 and hash2 do not match.");

if (password1.CompareToHash(hash3))
    Console.WriteLine("hash1 and hash3 match.");
else
    Console.WriteLine("hash1 and hash3 do not match.");
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following:

```
public async Task<IUser> Authenticate(ICredentials credentials)
{
    using var connection = _databaseGateway.Connection;
    connection.Open();
    var users = await connection.GetAllAsync<User>();
    const int expectedUserCount = 1;
    var existingUsers = users
        .Where(u => u.Username == credentials.Username);

    if (existingUsers.Count() != expectedUserCount)
        throw new AuthenticationException(Error.UserDoesNotExist,
            "Error: There is no single user exists with the username given.");
    var existingUser = existingUsers.Single();

    var salt = existingUser.PasswordSalt;
    // TURN ON FOR REGISTERING USER PW
    // salt = PasswordHash.ScryptGenerateSalt();
    var password = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials.Password);
    var hash = PasswordHash.ScryptHashBinary(password, salt);
    // TURN ON FOR REGISTERING USER PW
    // await connection.ExecuteAsync(
    //    "UPDATE user SET PasswordHash=@hash, PasswordSalt=@salt WHERE UserName=@username;",
    //    new {hash, salt, username = credentials.Username});

    var wrongPassword = !hash.SequenceEqual(existingUser.PasswordHash);

    if (wrongPassword)
        throw new AuthenticationException(Error.WrongPassword,
            "Error: Incorrect Password.");

    return AddToken(existingUser);
}
```

The suspicion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61572506/how-to-authenticate-user-with-hashed-password/61573352#comment108914865_61572506) was correct I think. It seems to generate random salt each time with `string` overloads of the method(s).

---

I then ended up adding a helper class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Sodium;

namespace Services
{
    public static class HashingService
    {
        public static bool IsGeneratedBy(
            this IEnumerable<byte> existingHash,
            string plaintextPassword,
            byte[] salt
        )
        {
            var password = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintextPassword);
            var generatedHash = PasswordHash.ScryptHashBinary(password, salt);
            var passwordIsCorrect = generatedHash.SequenceEqual(existingHash);
            return passwordIsCorrect;
        }
    }
}
```

and used it like:

```
public async Task<IUser> Authenticate(ICredentials credentials)
{
    using var connection = _databaseGateway.Connection;
    connection.Open();
    var users = await connection.GetAllAsync<User>();
    const int expectedUserCount = 1;
    var existingUser = users
        .Single(u => u.Username == credentials.Username);

    var wrongPassword = !existingUser.PasswordHash.IsGeneratedBy(
        credentials.Password, existingUser.PasswordSalt);

    if (wrongPassword)
        throw new AuthenticationException(Error.WrongPassword,
            "Error: Incorrect Password.");

    return AddToken(existingUser);
}
```